# python crashes with core dump when using python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tcl, coredump

I have written a multi-threaded python script with threading library. The python script is calling underlying TCL code (expect/send) to interact with my devices. The python threads share the same TCL interpreter. When the python script is not multi-threaded, it works fine. But now python always crashes saying segmentation fault with a core dump. It does not always crash at the same line but the lines are close.

I am pasting the traceback as below. I don't have any experience in debugging this so can someone please help? My python version is 3.4.3. Thank you in advance for help.

```
*** glibc detected *** python: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09b7bec8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x18fa15]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0x193a89]
/auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtcl8.4.so(TclpFree+0x1d)[0xf769a1ad]
/auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtcl8.4.so(Tcl_Free+0x1d)[0xf76a248d]
                         /lib/libresolv-2.5.so

069e5000-069f8000 rw-p 00129000 08:03 2947401                           /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
069f8000-069fc000 rw-p 069f8000 00:00 0 
069fe000-06a2b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 90367                              /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
06a2b000-06a2c000 rw-p 0002d000 08:03 90367                              /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
08048000-081fc000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 33225197                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/bin/python3.4
081fc000-0823f000 rw-p 001b3000 00:22 33225197                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/bin/python3.4
0823f000-08255000 rw-p 0823f000 00:00 0 
08de6000-0b78b000 rw-p 08de6000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
ed400000-ed441000 rw-p ed400000 00:00 0 
ed441000-ed500000 ---p ed441000 00:00 0 
ed600000-ed7f6000 rw-p ed600000 00:00 0 
ed7f6000-ed800000 ---p ed7f6000 00:00 0 
ed800000-ed9f4000 rw-p ed800000 00:00 0 
ed9f4000-eda00000 ---p ed9f4000 00:00 0 
eda00000-edbfc000 rw-p eda00000 00:00 0 
edbfc000-edc00000 ---p edbfc000 00:00 0 
edc00000-edd00000 rw-p edc00000 00:00 0 
edd36000-eddb2000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 15575474                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/tdom0.8.3/libtdom0.8.3.so
eddb2000-eddb8000 rw-p 0007c000 00:22 15575474                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/tdom0.8.3/libtdom0.8.3.so
ede00000-edefe000 rw-p ede00000 00:00 0 
edefe000-edf00000 ---p edefe000 00:00 0 
edf7b000-ee03b000 rw-p edf7b000 00:00 0 
ee03b000-ee03c000 ---p ee03b000 00:00 0 
ee03c000-eea3c000 rwxp ee03c000 00:00 0 
eea3c000-eea3d000 ---p eea3c000 00:00 0 
eea3d000-ef43d000 rwxp eea3d000 00:00 0 
ef43d000-ef43e000 ---p ef43d000 00:00 0 
ef43e000-efe3e000 rwxp ef43e000 00:00 0 
efe3e000-efe3f000 ---p efe3e000 00:00 0 
efe3f000-f083f000 rwxp efe3f000 00:00 0 
f083f000-f09ff000 rw-p f083f000 00:00 0 
f09ff000-f0a00000 ---p f09ff000 00:00 0 
f0a00000-f1400000 rwxp f0a00000 00:00 0 
f1400000-f1500000 rw-p f1400000 00:00 0 
f1509000-f150a000 ---p f1509000 00:00 0 
f150a000-f1f0a000 rwxp f150a000 00:00 0 
f1f0a000-f1f0b000 ---p f1f0a000 00:00 0 
f1f0b000-f290b000 rwxp f1f0b000 00:00 0 
f290b000-f290c000 ---p f290b000 00:00 0 
f290c000-f330c000 rwxp f290c000 00:00 0 
f330c000-f330d000 ---p f330c000 00:00 0 
f330d000-f3d0d000 rwxp f330d000 00:00 0 
f3d0d000-f3d0e000 ---p f3d0d000 00:00 0 
f3d0e000-f470e000 rwxp f3d0e000 00:00 0 
f470e000-f4717000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2946373                            /lib/libcrypt-2.5.so
f4717000-f4718000 r--p 00008000 08:03 2946373                            /lib/libcrypt-2.5.so
f4718000-f4719000 rw-p 00009000 08:03 2946373                            /lib/libcrypt-2.5.so
f4719000-f4740000 rw-p f4719000 00:00 0 
f4740000-f4774000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3961091                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtcacheipc.so.1.0.0
f4774000-f4775000 rw-p 00034000 08:03 3961091                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtcacheipc.so.1.0.0
f4775000-f47df000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3961097                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtutil.so.1.0.0
f47df000-f47e0000 rw-p 0006a000 08:03 3961097                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtutil.so.1.0.0
f47e0000-f47f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3961095                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtsmartcache.so.1.0.0
f47f4000-f47f5000 rw-p 00013000 08:03 3961095                            /opt/quest/lib/libvtsmartcache.so.1.0.0
f47f5000-f480a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3961099                            /opt/quest/lib/nss/libnss_vas4.so.2
f480a000-f480b000 rw-p 00014000 08:03 3961099                            /opt/quest/lib/nss/libnss_vas4.so.2
f480b000-f4815000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2946277                            /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
f4815000-f4816000 r--p 00009000 08:03 2946277                            /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
f4816000-f4817000 rw-p 0000a000 08:03 2946277                            /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
f4821000-f4822000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 198086                             /usr/lib/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
f4822000-f4824000 rw-p 00000000 08:03 198086                             /usr/lib/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
f4824000-f482b000 r--s 00000000 08:03 198146                             /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
f482b000-f4bfc000 rw-p f482b000 00:00 0 
f4bfc000-f4c37000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 256882619                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libcurl.so.4
f4c37000-f4c38000 rw-p 0003b000 00:21 256882619                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libcurl.so.4
f4c38000-f4d8a000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 259902543                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libACE.so.5.5.6
f4d8a000-f4d94000 rw-p 00152000 00:21 259902543                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libACE.so.5.5.6
f4d94000-f4d96000 rw-p f4d94000 00:00 0 
f4d96000-f5145000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 256151631                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libxerces-c.so.27
f5145000-f5178000 rw-p 003af000 00:21 256151631                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libxerces-c.so.27
f5178000-f51af000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257135846                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libstcutils.so
f51af000-f51b0000 rw-p 00036000 00:21 257135846                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libstcutils.so
f51b0000-f51b8000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 259663728                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libminiz.so.1.2.3    
f51b9000-f51d8000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257889948                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_filesystem-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f51d8000-f51d9000 rw-p 0001e000 00:21 257889948                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_filesystem-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f51d9000-f52d1000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257379238                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_regex-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f52d1000-f52d4000 rw-p 000f7000 00:21 257379238                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_regex-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f52d4000-f52de000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257135844                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libgcc_s.so.1
f52de000-f52df000 rw-p 00009000 00:21 257135844                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libgcc_s.so.1
f52df000-f53b2000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257154828                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libstdc++.so.6
f53b2000-f53b7000 rw-p 000d2000 00:21 257154828                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libstdc++.so.6
f5bdd000-f5bec000 rw-p 006bd000 00:21 256030729                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libstcbase.so
f5bec000-f5bfa000 rw-p f5bec000 00:00 0 
f5bfa000-f5c12000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 259697540                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libsTcl.so
f5c12000-f5c13000 rw-p 00018000 00:21 259697540                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libsTcl.so
f5c13000-f5c36000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257580704                          /auto/cafy_dev/prod_ws/tcl_ats_tree/cafy_dev_prod/ats5.3.0/lib/cisco-shared/vendor/tclextensions/mpexpr1.1/linux/libMpexpr11.so
f5c36000-f5c37000 rw-p 00023000 00:21 257580704                          /auto/cafy_dev/prod_ws/tcl_ats_tree/cafy_dev_prod/ats5.3.0/lib/cisco-shared/vendor/tclextensions/mpexpr1.1/linux/libMpexpr11.so
f5c37000-f5e78000 rw-p f5c37000 00:00 0 
f5e78000-f5f5f000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257633241                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libiconv.so.2.5.1
f5f5f000-f5f60000 rw-p 000e7000 00:21 257633241                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libiconv.so.2.5.1
f5f60000-f6015000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257643848                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
f6015000-f601b000 rw-p 000b4000 00:21 257643848                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libgcrypt.so.20.0.3
f601b000-f601c000 rw-p f601b000 00:00 0 
f601c000-f6048000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257642554                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/liblzma.so.5.2.1
f6048000-f6049000 rw-p 0002b000 00:21 257642554                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/liblzma.so.5.2.1
f6049000-f61be000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257568112                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libxml2.so.2.9.2
f61be000-f61c3000 rw-p 00175000 00:21 257568112                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libxml2.so.2.9.2
f61c3000-f61c4000 rw-p f61c3000 00:00 0 
f61c4000-f6205000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257568119                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libxslt.so.1.1.28
f6205000-f6206000 rw-p 00041000 00:21 257568119                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libxslt.so.1.1.28
f6206000-f639b000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 11088100                           /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lxml-3.4.4-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
f639b000-f63c2000 rw-p 00194000 00:26 11088100                           /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lxml-3.4.4-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
f63c2000-f6485000 rw-p f63c2000 00:00 0 
f6485000-f64cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 75040                              /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.5
f64cd000-f64d5000 rw-p 00048000 08:03 75040                              /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.5
f64d5000-f64d6000 rw-p f64d5000 00:00 0 
f64d6000-f6505000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 75072                              /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
f6505000-f6509000 rw-p 0002f000 08:03 75072                              /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
f6509000-f650a000 rw-p f6509000 00:00 0 
f650a000-f650b000 ---p f650a000 00:00 0 
f650b000-f6f0b000 rwxp f650b000 00:00 0 
f6f0b000-f6f4b000 rw-p f6f0b000 00:00 0 
f6f4b000-f6f4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2946364                            /lib/libuuid.so.1.2
f6f4e000-f6f4f000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 2946364                            /lib/libuuid.so.1.2
f6f53000-f6f58000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590675                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-34m.so
f6f58000-f6f5a000 rw-p 00004000 00:22 22590675                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-34m.so
f6f5a000-f6f62000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 6699022                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_Blowfish.cpython-34m.so
f6f62000-f6f63000 rw-p 00007000 00:26 6699022                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_Blowfish.cpython-34m.so
f6f63000-f7023000 rw-p f6f63000 00:00 0 
f7023000-f7035000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589270                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-34m.so
f7035000-f7038000 rw-p 00011000 00:22 19589270                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-34m.so
f7038000-f7078000 rw-p f7038000 00:00 0 
f7078000-f70d5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 75212                              /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
f70d5000-f70d7000 rw-p 0005d000 08:03 75212                              /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
f70d7000-f71d8000 rw-p f70d7000 00:00 0 
f71d9000-f71dc000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257937056                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_system-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f71dc000-f71dd000 rw-p 00002000 00:21 257937056                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/spirent/Spirent_TestCenter_4.53/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/libboost_system-gcc40-mt-1_46_1.so.1.46.1
f71dd000-f71e9000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 6699026                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.cpython-34m.so
f71e9000-f71ea000 rw-p 0000b000 00:26 6699026                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.cpython-34m.so
f71ea000-f71ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257643844                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libexslt.so.0.8.17
f71ff000-f7200000 rw-p 00014000 00:21 257643844                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libexslt.so.0.8.17
f7200000-f7340000 rw-p f7200000 00:00 0 
f7340000-f7347000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589264                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-34m.so
f7347000-f7348000 rw-p 00007000 00:22 19589264                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-34m.so
f7348000-f73c8000 rw-p f7348000 00:00 0 
f73c8000-f73fd000 r--s 00000000 08:05 974424                             /var/db/nscd/hosts
f73fd000-f74a2000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323601                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-34m.so
f74a2000-f74b8000 rw-p 000a4000 00:22 18323601                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-34m.so
f74b8000-f74f8000 rw-p f74b8000 00:00 0 
f74f8000-f7510000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 25842774                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/itcl3.4/libitcl3.4.so
f7510000-f7511000 rw-p 00018000 00:22 25842774                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/itcl3.4/libitcl3.4.so
f7511000-f7531000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 23465927                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/Trf2.1.2/libTrf2.1.2.so
f7531000-f7535000 rw-p 00020000 00:22 23465927                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/Trf2.1.2/libTrf2.1.2.so
f7536000-f7546000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257633236                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
f7546000-f7547000 rw-p 0000f000 00:21 257633236                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libgpg-error.so.0.15.0
f7547000-f75c7000 rw-p f7547000 00:00 0 
f75c7000-f75f2000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 17889524                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/expect5.44.1.9/libexpect5.44.1.9.so
f75f2000-f75f4000 rw-p 0002b000 00:22 17889524                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/expect5.44.1.9/libexpect5.44.1.9.so
f75f4000-f75f7000 rw-p f75f4000 00:00 0 
f75f7000-f761b000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19308175                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/tclx8.4/libtclx8.4.so
f761b000-f761c000 rw-p 00023000 00:22 19308175                           /auto/ttsw/ActiveTcl/8.4.19.1.286040/lib/tclx8.4/libtclx8.4.so
f761c000-f765c000 rw-p f761c000 00:00 0 
f765c000-f7677000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590676                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m.so
f7677000-f767a000 rw-p 0001a000 00:22 22590676                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m.so
f767a000-f7726000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257642559                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtcl8.4.so
f7726000-f7730000 rw-p 000ac000 00:21 257642559                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtcl8.4.so
f7730000-f7731000 rw-p f7730000 00:00 0 
f7731000-f7804000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257642562                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtk8.4.so
f7804000-f7810000 rw-p 000d2000 00:21 257642562                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libtk8.4.so
f7810000-f7911000 rw-p f7810000 00:00 0 
f7911000-f7913000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137288                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-34m.so
f7913000-f7915000 rw-p 00001000 00:22 3137288                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-34m.so
f7915000-f7a16000 rw-p f7915000 00:00 0 
f7a16000-f7a18000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 6699021                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.cpython-34m.so
f7a18000-f7a19000 rw-p 00001000 00:26 6699021                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.cpython-34m.so
f7a19000-f7a20000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 2658997                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.cpython-34m.so
f7a20000-f7a21000 rw-p 00007000 00:26 2658997                            /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.cpython-34m.so
f7a21000-f7a25000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323594                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-34m.so
f7a25000-f7a27000 rw-p 00003000 00:22 18323594                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-34m.so
f7a27000-f7a34000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589277                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-34m.so
f7a34000-f7a36000 rw-p 0000d000 00:22 19589277                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-34m.so
f7a36000-f7ab6000 rw-p f7a36000 00:00 0 
f7ab6000-f7abb000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323604                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-34m.so
f7abb000-f7abd000 rw-p 00004000 00:22 18323604                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-34m.so
f7abd000-f7aef000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323593                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-34m.so
f7aef000-f7af2000 rw-p 00032000 00:22 18323593                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-34m.so
f7af2000-f7b00000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589278                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-34m.so
f7b00000-f7b03000 rw-p 0000e000 00:22 19589278                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-34m.so
f7b03000-f7b83000 rw-p f7b03000 00:00 0 
f7b83000-f7b85000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589272                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-34m.so
f7b85000-f7b86000 rw-p 00001000 00:22 19589272                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-34m.so
f7b86000-f7b89000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590685                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-34m.so
f7b89000-f7b8a000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 22590685                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-34m.so
f7b8a000-f7c0a000 rw-p f7b8a000 00:00 0 
f7c0a000-f7c0c000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 663249                             /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_psutil_linux.cpython-34m.so
f7c0c000-f7c0d000 rw-p 00001000 00:26 663249                             /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_psutil_linux.cpython-34m.so
f7c0d000-f7c8d000 rw-p f7c0d000 00:00 0 
f7c8d000-f7ca4000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 257568123                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libz.so.1.2.8
f7ca4000-f7ca5000 rw-p 00016000 00:21 257568123                          /auto/cafy_dev/tools/libs/libz.so.1.2.8
f7ca5000-f7ca9000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137286                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-34m.so
f7ca9000-f7caa000 rw-p 00003000 00:22 3137286                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-34m.so
f7caa000-f7cb0000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589279                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-34m.so
f7cb0000-f7cb2000 rw-p 00005000 00:22 19589279                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-34m.so
f7cb2000-f7cc0000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590680                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-34m.so
f7cc0000-f7cc2000 rw-p 0000d000 00:22 22590680                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-34m.so
f7cc2000-f7d02000 rw-p f7cc2000 00:00 0 
f7d02000-f7d0a000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137284                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/array.cpython-34m.so
f7d0a000-f7d0c000 rw-p 00008000 00:22 3137284                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/array.cpython-34m.so
f7d0c000-f7d12000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137290                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/math.cpython-34m.so
f7d12000-f7d14000 rw-p 00005000 00:22 3137290                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/math.cpython-34m.so
f7d14000-f7d18000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323596                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/select.cpython-34m.so
f7d18000-f7d1a000 rw-p 00003000 00:22 18323596                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/select.cpython-34m.so
f7d1a000-f7d1d000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589271                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-34m.so
f7d1d000-f7d1e000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 19589271                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-34m.so
f7d1e000-f7d5f000 rw-p f7d1e000 00:00 0 
f7d5f000-f7d62000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 10975889                           /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_counter.cpython-34m.so
f7d62000-f7d63000 rw-p 00002000 00:26 10975889                           /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_counter.cpython-34m.so
f7d63000-f7d64000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590666                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-34m.so
f7d64000-f7d65000 rw-p 00001000 00:22 22590666                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-34m.so
f7d65000-f7d68000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589265                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_lsprof.cpython-34m.so
f7d68000-f7d69000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 19589265                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_lsprof.cpython-34m.so
f7d69000-f7d6c000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323599                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-34m.so
f7d6c000-f7d6e000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 18323599                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-34m.so
f7d6e000-f7d70000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323595                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/resource.cpython-34m.so
f7d70000-f7d71000 rw-p 00001000 00:22 18323595                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/resource.cpython-34m.so
f7d71000-f7d72000 rwxp f7d71000 00:00 0 
f7d72000-f7d7b000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137283                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-34m.so
f7d7b000-f7d7c000 rw-p 00009000 00:22 3137283                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-34m.so
f7d7c000-f7d86000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590683                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_elementtree.cpython-34m.so
f7d86000-f7d87000 rw-p 0000a000 00:22 22590683                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_elementtree.cpython-34m.so
f7d87000-f7d88000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589269                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m.so
f7d88000-f7d89000 rw-p 00000000 00:22 19589269                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m.so
f7d89000-f7d8b000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590667                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-34m.so
f7d8b000-f7d8c000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 22590667                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-34m.so
f7d8c000-f7d8e000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 3137289                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-34m.so
f7d8e000-f7d8f000 rw-p 00001000 00:22 3137289                            /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-34m.so
f7d8f000-f7dcf000 rw-p f7d8f000 00:00 0 
f7dcf000-f7dd3000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 18323600                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/time.cpython-34m.so
f7dd3000-f7dd6000 rw-p 00003000 00:22 18323600                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/time.cpython-34m.so
f7dd6000-f7e16000 rw-p f7dd6000 00:00 0 
f7e16000-f7e18000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 22590686                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-34m.so
f7e18000-f7e1a000 rw-p 00002000 00:22 22590686                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-34m.so
f7e1a000-f7f9c000 rw-p f7e1a000 00:00 0 
f7f9c000-f7f9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2946293                            /lib/libutil-2.5.so
f7f9e000-f7f9f000 r--p 00001000 08:03 2946293                            /lib/libutil-2.5.so
f7f9f000-f7fa0000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 2946293                            /lib/libutil-2.5.so
f7fa0000-f7fa1000 r-xp 00000000 00:26 663250                             /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_psutil_posix.cpython-34m.so
f7fa1000-f7fa2000 rw-p 00000000 00:26 663250                             /auto/panini_slice_reset/xspeed_new/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_psutil_posix.cpython-34m.so
f7fa2000-f7faf000 r-xp 00000000 00:22 19589276                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-34m.so
f7faf000-f7fb4000 rw-p 0000c000 00:22 19589276                           /auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-34m.so
f7fb4000-f7fb5000 rw-p f7fb4000 00:00 0 
fff84000-fffa2000 rwxp 7ffffffdf000 00:00 0                              [stack]
fffa2000-fffa4000 rw-p 7fffffffd000 00:00 0 
ffffe000-fffff000 r-xp ffffe000 00:00 0 
  adding: bll.dmp.log (deflated 46%)
  adding: bll.log (deflated 93%)
  adding: client.bll.log (deflated 85%)
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: could you also share the requisite portion of the code?

Comment: thanks for reply. the code is quite long and uses my own library. Not sure which portion would be helpful. Can you be more detailed about what is needed?

Comment: Sharing a Tcl intepreter between threads isn't supported and is not expected to work. Thats not how Tcl interpreters are supposed to work (as they use a lot of thread local data).

Answer (score 3):

> The python threads share the same TCL interpreter.

Don't do that. Tcl uses thread-specific data *intensively* inside its implementation to reduce the number of locks it uses (e.g., it doesn't need any kind of global interpreter lock at all). This means that using a Tcl interpreter from two different OS threads — however you achieve that — is going to break horribly.

Designate one Python thread to look after that Tcl interpreter and get all the other threads to send messages to and from that thread. For running something that is I/O-based (such as interacting with a subprocess via Expect) that will not impose a significant overhead.